# Time Complexity of 3 sum

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have provided a snippet of the code for solving the 3 sum problem below.

```
       int N = 10; 

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)// this line gets executed N times
    for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)// this line gets executed N(N-1) times
      for (int k = j+1; k < N; k++)// this line gets executed  N(N-1)(N-2) times
         if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0)// How many times does this line gets executed
             cnt++;
```

The textbook I am using said that the line

```
if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0)
```

gets executed (N(N-1)(N-2))/6 times.
but from my analysis, the statement gets executed (N(N-1)(N-2))

Why is there a division by 6, whats is the proof of that.

Comment: Basically, N(N-1)(N-2) is the number of permutations you can pick from the integers in the range from 1 to N.  The loop only picks the permutations i, j, k with i < j< k.  Only one of the 6 permutations of i, j, k is sorted in ascending order, hence the total number of iterations in the nested loop is N(N-1)(N-2)/6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
        ;
```

The first loop will execute `N` iterations. That much is clear and unambiguous.

The second loop will execute:

- `N - 1` iterations when `i == 0`
- `N - 2` iterations when `i == 1`
- `N - 3` iterations when `i == 2`

and so on. You can use induction to prove how many iterations this loop will do, and then you can extend to 3 loops.

Hint: The sum 1 + 2 + ... + (N - 2) + (N - 1) can be proven to equal N * (N - 1) / 2

Answer (score 2):

Your code is actually doing a permutation and composition problem: Take three different elements from n elements and see if their sum is zero. So how many combinations of three different elements are extracted from n elements?  Math tells you (N,3)=N*(N-1)*(N-2)/3!=N*(N-1)*(N-2)/6

Answer (score 1):

I think looking at this by inspection might make it clear.  Consider the case where `N = 3`:

```
i = 0, 1, 2
j = 1, 2
k = 2
```

The inner `if` statement can only execute once, because only `k = 2` is permissible by the inner most loop, and this would happen when `i = 0` and `j = 1`.  So `N(N-1)(N-2)/6 = 3*2*1/6 = 1`, and this makes sense.  You can build up to more complex cases, or even think of an inductive proof if you like that sort of thing.

About the issue of the `1/6` factor, from the point of view of running time, it doesn't matter, because `O(1/6 * N^3)` is the same as `O(N^3)`.  The code you showed us should behave as `O(N^3)` in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

```
For i = 0, j = 1, k will execute for 2 to N-1 ie if statement will execute for N-2 times.
For i = 0, j = 2, k will execute for 3 to N-1 ie if statement will execute for N-3 times.
:
:
For i = 0, j = N-2, k will execute for N-1 to N-1 ie if statement will execute for 1 times.

That means for i = 0, if statement will execute for :
N-2 + N-3 + .... +1 = (N-2)(N-1)/2.

For i = 1, j = 2, k will execute for 3 to N-1 ie if statement will execute for N-3 times.
For i = 1, j = 3, k will execute for 4 to N-1 ie if statement will execute for N-4 times.
:
:
For i = 1, j = N-2, k will execute for N-1 to N-1 ie if statement will execute for 1 times.

And for i = 1, if statement will execute for :
N-3 + N-4 + .... +1 = (N-3)(N-2)/2.

*
*
For i = N-4, j = N-3, k will execute for N-2 to N-1 ie if statement will execute for 2 times.
For i = N-4, j = N-2, k will execute for N-1 to N-1 ie if statement will execute for 1 times.

And for i = N-4, if statement will execute for :
2+1 = (2)(3)/2.

For i = N-3, j = N-2, k will execute for N-1 to N-1 ie if statement will execute for 1 times.
For i = N-3, j = N-1, k will fail for condition ie if statement will execute for 0 times.
ie (1)(1+1)/2

And for i = N-3, if statement will execute for :
1 = (1)(2)/2.




ie.
i = 0, if statement will execute for (N-2)(N-1)/2
i = 1, if statement will execute for (N-3)(N-2)/2
i = 2, if statement will execute for (N-4)(N-3)/2
.
.
i = N-5, if statement will execute for (3*4)/2
i = N-4, if statement will execute for (2*3)/2
i = N-3, if statement will execute for (1*2)/2

That means total number of times if statement executed is
= (N-2)(N-1)/2 + (N-3)(N-2)/2 + (N-4)(N-3)/2 + ... + (2)(3)/2 + (1)(2)/2
= (1/2)[ 1*2 + 2*3 + 3*4 + ... + (N-2)(N-1)]
= (1/2)[ (N-2)(N-1)(N)/3 ]
= (N)(N+1)(N+2)/6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think it in another way.
Your goal is to choose 3 numbers and the sum is a target(0).
So this problem will be converted into a Permutation problem.
So the answer is
[image]
And the result is [image]
So that you know how 6 comes!

Additionally, you can use O(n^2) to solve this problem:
By using 2 pointers, left begin at i + 1 and right begin from end.
Here is the code written in Java:

```java
public int threeSum(int[] nums) { //O(n) Complexity
        int len = nums.length;
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len - 2; i++) { //i at most to len - 3 O(n)
            int left = i + 1;
            int right = len - 1;
            while (left < right) { //O(n)
                int sum = nums[i] + nums[left] + nums[right];
                if (sum < 0) left++;
                else if (sum > 0) right--;
                else cnt++;
            }
        }
        return cnt;
    }
```

[image]